# weight changer view doesn´t save the order applied. why?

Tags: views

I have a D6 site with views 3 and latest version of weight module.

upon clicking the Save button ..it doesn´t apply the weights

Is there any bug on the module itself?

here-s my configuration..
[image]
[image]

Comment: You don't have anything listed in your sort criteria.  I would imagine the weights are being set, but as you're not sorting by said weights, it _appears_ that they aren't!

Comment: thanx :) you're right. it was saving but my view for ordering wasn't sorting. you can put an answer so I can validate it.